# Java Sockets : How to keep the socket 'open' after sending a file?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

first off forgive my programming speak as im not very good at explaining things.

So, what i have done is created a simple chat program that is able to communicate over LAN. I recently made it so i can send files over the socket

This is the frame which has a button that opens a file chooser shown below.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Images", "jpg", "gif","png");
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "Document", "docx", "doc","pdf","pptx");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter2);
            Component parent = null;
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File filesend = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                int count;
                OutputStream out;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                try {
                    c.setMessage("fsendnow");// Sends a command to the server so it knows that im sending a file so it can prepare to receive it
                    c.msgOut();



                    out = c.getMyClient().getOutputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filesend));
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                         out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                         out.flush();
                    }

                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And this is the code that receives the file

```
}else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("fsendnow")){

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("a.png");
                    BufferedOutputStream out2 = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    int count;
                    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                    while((count=in.read(buffer)) >=0){
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    fos.close();

                    }else{
                    cf.printMsg(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+": "+line);
                }
```

The problem im facing is after i send a file, it does appear in the folder, however, im unable to open it as it is "currently being used". My guess is that the running program is still writing bytes to it. Because of this socket still "being used" i cannot do anything with the program (send messages / more files). I tried closing the socket here however, i still need it to send messages until i exit the chat window. What should i do? Should i open a new socket connection? I really dont want to do this and I honestly do not want to create a threaded server.

```
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                         out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                         out.flush();
                    }
                    //c.getMyClient().close();  CLOSES THE SOCKET
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

so how do i tell java that im done sending the file and to stop the image from "reading". Sorry in advance if its a noob question.

Comment: Are you closing the file at the end?

Comment: i am not sure but i think the read(buffer) call will block the thread and output stream to file will never closed.

Comment: for solving this i think first you need to receive the total number of byte file has and increment at read iteration and break the loop if the byte count reach to total number of byte in file.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are expecting to read 8192 bytes, from socket, and you are trying to write 8192 bytes  in the file , but it could be that you recive less bytes than 8192, from socket, and this could block the file until the 8192 bytes has been written to file

Also, I suggest to read first the 8192 bytes and when you have al the buffer write it, because you are always writting from offset 0:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                     out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                     out.flush();
                }
```